# How to get append value in jquery or other method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get append value in jquery or other method?

I want to show the the value Hello Append!!! append value on `<div id="get_append_value"></div>` tag,

My Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show_append_value").append("Hello Append!!!");
});
```

My Html code

```
<body>
  <div id="show_append_value"></div>
  <div id="show_hello_world">Hello World!!!</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="get_append_value"></div <!--need to use jquery to show 'Hello Append!!! on it, but result is empty'-->
  <div id="get_hello_world"></div>
</body>
```

```
<script>
var $show_value = $('#show_append_value').html();
$('#get_append_value').html($show_value);
var $show_value2 = $('#show_hello_world').html();
$('#get_hello_world').html($show_value2);
</script>
```

This result:

```
Hello Append!!!
Hello World!!!


Hello World!!!
```

Although it can show the value on `<div id="show_append_value">` and `<div id="show_hello_world">`,  it doesn't give the appended value to show on `<div id="get_append_value"></div>` , it is empty

Can anyone teach me how to get the appended value in jquery or other method to show  the value on other div tag?

Comment: If you want to append value of `#show_hello_world` to `#get_append_value` then try this`$('#get_append_value').append($('#show_hello_world').text());`

Comment: thanks , but i wants to get  value of  #show_append_value  to  #get_append_value..... i try this method $('#get_append_value').append($('#show_append_value').text());,  but it still empty...............

Comment: Okay try this `$('#get_append_value').append($('#show_hello_world').html());` Now i'm using `html()` it works fine from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code executes in the wrong order.

Any code that is put directly in a `script` tag, outside of any call-back, is executed *before* what you have inside the `ready` call back, so that means `Hello Append!!` is not yet in your document when you are fetching it.

To solve this, put all of your code in the `ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show_append_value").append("Hello Append!!!");

  var $show_value = $('#show_append_value').html();
  $('#get_append_value').html($show_value);
  var $show_value2 = $('#show_hello_world').html();
  $('#get_hello_world').html($show_value2);
});
```